# Search for at least 1 hit, mysql and join

Tags: mysql, join, count

i have the following sql query

```
SELECT 
    vmm_user.username, 
    vmm_songs.*, 
    vmm_albums.desc, 
    vmm_albums.release, 
    vmm_albums.name, 
    AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) AS ratingavg,
    COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) AS ratingcount
FROM 
    vmm_songs 
LEFT JOIN 
    vmm_user 
ON 
    vmm_songs.userid=vmm_user.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    vmm_albums 
ON 
    vmm_songs.albumid=vmm_albums.id 
LEFT JOIN  
    vmm_songrating  
ON 
    vmm_songs.id=vmm_songrating.songid 
GROUP BY 
    vmm_songs.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) >= 2 
ORDER BY
    AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) DESC
LIMIT 
    10
```

this works fine but now i have to know if a user already voted for a song and thats my problem

the rating table looks like this

id|songid|userid|rating

i tried something like this

```
SELECT 
...
 COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) as hasvoted  
...
OUTER JOIN 
    vmm_songrating
ON 
    vmm_songrating.userid = $id
...
```

$id is the user session id

but it doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding something like this to the selected fields

```
SUM(case when vmm_songrating.userid = $id then 1 end) as hasvoted
```

Comment: sorry that i'm asking again but it is possible to select only the song with the highest rating from an album?